# What is the minimum ammount of Memory required per JVM & C++ Instance?

Tags: java, python, c++, memory-management, jvm

I plan to develop an online compiler for a Hackathon at my organisation. The process I have in mind is to use a core Java app to trigger a shell command for each programming language, implement process builder and then trigger the javac/java or python or gcc command by forking a unix shell. So basically per user, I'll be forking a jvm or c++ process via a java app, which will compile and excute the program and then return the output. The programs will mostly be algotihmic challenges in nature. I need to know, whats the mimimum resources a jvm or a python or C program excution may take so that I can estimate the server size for around 200 users. I know that for jvm we can set the min and max heap size, but how much ram will the jvm itsef take other than heap, stak and thread space. What would the estimation look like.

Comment: Just use an Apache web server, configure mod_cgi (mostly already configured) and hook up a perl CGI script which reads the form data and executes the program. Its that simple.

Comment: @Arunmu Well, the challenge is people can code infinite loops and lengthy programs. I need to restrict the heap space for each of them.

Comment: I see, so this is not relevant to C/C++, only for python and Java, because for C/C++ programs, the only memory footprint besides the executable size is the heap/stack allocation that the program does internally (which could be anything depending upon the logic of the program)

Comment: @Arunmu There has to be a way for us to restrict the ammount of memory consumed by a c or c++ process. Maybe use a wait and kill the process using unix.

Comment: Use `ulimit -v`, but this will be acted on all the processes. So your memory limit should be `expected_program_memory + max_of(jvm_memory, python_vm_memory)` OR something close to it. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1424/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-memory-a-particular-process-can-use-in-uni

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JVM minimum heap size recommendation reasons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382132/jvm-minimum-heap-size-recommendation-reasons)